# Not showing the image of img tag

Tags: html

I have a image tag on html code. which is used to generate a pdf. particular image for the image tag is taking from the server. but it is not showing the image. followings code is img tag what I have tried.

```
<img class="characteristics-image" src="https:://translate.orivet.com/images/last-page-2.png">
```

What is the wrong with this?

Comment: Typo in the URL: `https:://` with double colon instead of `https://`

Answer (score 1):

"https:://sales.com/images/img.png" is not a valid URL.
You meant "https://sales.com/images/img.png".

Comment: Can you please see the question again